# Removing nonlinear terms

Tags: nonlinear

The following is a condensed version of a lengthy expression. My objective is to eliminate nonlinear terms from an expression.

The vector containing the variables is:

```
veclst = {Subscript[A, 11], Subscript[A, 13], Subscript[A, 15]};
```

The reduced form of the expression is:

```
expr = a Subscript[A, 11] Subscript[A, 13] + b Subscript[A, 15] + 
c Subscript[A, 15] Subscript[A, 13] + d Subscript[A, 13]^2
```

My objective is to eliminate nonlinear terms in the expression (expression) in terms of the variables specified in veclst.

I appreciate your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This:

```
Total[Map[If[Total[Exponent[#, veclst]] > 1, Nothing, #] &, MonomialList[expr]]]

(*b Subscript[A, 15]*)
```

Answer (score 6):

Since

```
 Internal`LinearQ[5,x]
```

Gives false, (is this a bug or by design?) as per comment below, the following version accounts for such cases.

```
veclst = {Subscript[A, 11], Subscript[A, 13], Subscript[A, 15]};
expr = a Subscript[A, 11] Subscript[A, 13] + b Subscript[A, 15] + 
  c Subscript[A, 15] Subscript[A, 13] + d Subscript[A, 13]^2 + 5 + x;
List @@ expr
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now do (*thanks to hints below for shorter code *)

```
sel = If[DisjointQ[Variables[#],veclst],True,Internal`LinearQ[#,veclst]] & /@List@@expr
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
Pick[expr, sel] (*shorter version thanks to Michael E2 *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Old answer

Another option is to use **Internal`LinearQ**

You can find the non-linear term using

```
sel = Internal`LinearQ[#, veclst] & /@ List @@ expr
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So only the 3rd term is linear. Now you can do

```
Total@Pick[List @@ expr, sel]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Pick[expr, sel]` is shorter. :)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2 , yes better.

Comment: Thanks @Nasser. Your approach will remove constant terms that don't have any variable.

Comment: @qahtah I would consider this a bug in "Internal`LinearQ"  :)

Comment: @Nasser Many thanks for your time and efforts.

Comment: @qahtah updated to account for such cases, hopefully it will be OK now.

Comment: I believe `Length[Intersection[Variables[#], veclst]] == 0` could also be shortened to `DisjointQ[Variables[#], veclst]`.

Comment: @NonDairyNeutrino  Yes, thanks for hint. This is better. I'll update my answer with your improvement. I did not look for shorter code at time, just wanted something that worked :)

Answer (score 6):

Another way:

```
CoefficientArrays[expr, veclst][[2]] . veclst
```

The polynomial does not need to be multiplied out:

```
SeedRandom[0];
var = {x, y, z};
poly = (1 + var . RandomInteger[2, 3])^2 *
    (1 - var . RandomInteger[2, 3])^3;
CoefficientArrays[poly, var][[2]] . var

(*  4 x + 4 y - 4 z  *)
```

Yet another way:

```
SeriesCoefficient[poly /. Thread[var -> t*var], {t, 0, 1}]

(*  4 (x + y - z)  *)
```

---

To get the degree-1 terms and lower:

Either of these (the first is how the docs show to do it for higher degree, but deg ≤ 1 can be done with `Apply`):

```
Fold[#1 + #2 . veclst &, CoefficientArrays[expr, veclst][[;; 2]]]
(* OR *)
#1 + #2 . veclst & @@ CoefficientArrays[poly, veclst][[;; 2]]
```

And

```
SeedRandom[0];
var = {x, y, z};
poly = (1 + var . RandomInteger[2, 3])^2*(1 - 
      var . RandomInteger[2, 3])^3;
Fold[#1 + #2 . var &, CoefficientArrays[poly, var][[;; 2]]]
(* OR *)
#1 + #2 . var & @@ CoefficientArrays[poly, var][[;; 2]]

(*  1 + 4 x + 4 y - 4 z  *)
```

Yet another way:

```
Normal@Series[poly /. Thread[var -> t*var], {t, 0, 1}] /. t -> 1

(*  1 + 4 (x + y - z)  *)
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael for your solution. Your code exculdes constant terms that don't have any variable.

Comment: @qahtah Constant terms are not linear, at least in some contexts, and there are none in your example (or the other answers). If you want them, they can be included very easily: add `CoefficientArrays[poly, var][[1]]` to the rest. Let me know if you want it, and I'll add it to the code.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Acutally what i needed was to remove higher order terms and keep lower order ones including the cosntant terms.

Comment: @qahtah OK, I added the codes for each method.